# Show that sum of divisors of a composite number $n$ is $> n+ \sqrt{n}$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum

The hint says to use :  When $1\lt d\lt n$, $1 \lt n/d \lt n$. If $d\le \sqrt{n}$, then $n/d \ge \sqrt{n}$

My try :

Since there will be atleast half divisors $> \sqrt{n}$,
the sum of divisors will be atleast $\dfrac{\tau (n)}{2}\sqrt{n}$
Not sure how to proceed further. Any help ?

Comment: Note that $n$ is a divisor of $n$.

Comment: Is $n$ a divisor of $n$? Must be, or else the assertion is false (take $n=4$). Hence .....

Comment: Oh yes! So that gives $ \gt n$, any help on how to work $\sqrt{n}$ part ?

Comment: You already did

Comment: thanks a lot! this turned out to be simple xD $ \sigma(n) \gt  n + \dfrac{\tau (n)}{2}\sqrt{n}  \gt  n + \sqrt{n} $

Answer (score 4):

Use the hint to prove that there exists a divisor $\sqrt{n} \leq d <n$.

Then $n$ and $d$ are divisors of $n$ and their sum is....

Comment: Nice :) Got it, thank you so much !!

Answer (score 2):

n is divisor of n , and there is atleast one $d >= \sqrt n$